# Entity Framework Table per Hierarchy Inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am trying to implement table per hierarchy inheritance with some of my database tables, e.g `Address`. I want to derive 3 classes from `Address`, these are `EmployeeAddress`, `CustomerAddress`, `SupplierAddress`.

```
+-------------------+------------------------+
| Address           |> EmployeeAddress       |
+-------------------+------------------------+
| ID                | ..                     |
| OwnerID           | EmployeeID             |
| OwnerCategory     | (condition: where = 0) |
| Street_1          | ..                     |
| Street_2          | ..                     |
| City              | ..                     |
| Province          | ..                     | 
| PostalCode        | ..                     |
+-------------------+------------------------+
                    |> CustomerAddress       |
                    +------------------------+
                    | ..                     |
                    | EmployeeID             |
                    | (condition: where = 1) |
                    | ..                     |
                    | ..                     |
                    | ..                     |
                    | ..                     | 
                    | ..                     |
                    +------------------------+
                    |> SupplierAddress       |
                    +------------------------+
                    |  ..                    |
                    | EmployeeID             |
                    | (condition: where = 2) |
                    | ..                     |
                    | ..                     |
                    | ..                     |
                    | ..                     | 
                    | ..                     |
                    +------------------------+
```

The problem is I keep getting errors...

When `Address` is **concrete**, and contains the `OwnerCategory` property:

> Error 3032: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line
>   178:Condition member 'addresses.OwnerCategory' with a condition other
>   than 'IsNull=False' is mapped. Either remove the condition on
>   addresses.OwnerCategory or remove it from the mapping.

When `Address` is **abstract** and contains the `OwnerCategory` property:

> Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 178:Condition member
>   'addresses.OwnerCategory' with a condition other than 'IsNull=False'
>   is mapped. Either remove the condition on addresses.OwnerCategory or
>   remove it from the mapping.

When `Address` is **concrete**, and **does not** contain the `OwnerCategory` property:

> 'DtcInvoicer.Database.Address' does not contain a definition for
>   'OwnerCategory' and no extension method 'OwnerCategory' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'DtcInvoicer.Database.Address' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and

> Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 177, 195:EntityTypes
>   Model.Address, Model.EmployeeAddress are being mapped to the same rows
>   in table addresses. Mapping conditions can be used to distinguish the
>   rows that these types are mapped to.

(I already have the condition set (when OwnerCategory = 0)

When `Address` is **abstract** and **does not** contain the `OwnerCategory` property:

> 'DtcInvoicer.Database.Address' does not contain a definition for
>   'OwnerCategory' and no extension method 'OwnerCategory' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'DtcInvoicer.Database.Address' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are using `OwnerCategory` in the condition for your inheritance it can't be mapped to a property. It also looks like you should also have `Address` set to abstract. Make sure you delete the property from your model and amend any code that was using it. The non mapping errors you mention appear to be the standard error when the compiler can't find a specific member so be sure to fix those spots.

Comment: Hey, I did try removing the `OwnerCateogry` property, and setting `Address` to abstract like I mentioned above. I get the error I mentioned at the very end.

Comment: Right, it looks like some other code was using `OwnerCategory`, you will have to modify that code not to use `OwnerCategory`.

Comment: Hey, seems you were right. It seems to be working now. I think i was using it elsewhere. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution to Error 3032 was adding `[NotMapped]` to my discriminator property